# Integration of Kony with Azure DevOps Server 2019

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019, temenos-quantum

One of my customer is Using Kony Platform to build Android and iOS mobile application using Kony Studio.

When working with Kony Studio, they are able to generate the Android .apk files in the bin folder, based on the debug or release mode.

When we try to integrate it with Azure DevOps Server 2019, the build pipeline passes, but when we check the logs we see an error about not able to generate the apk files for Android. The iOS files builds fine, but Android throws build error "with startup code failed".

We are currently using only "Ant" utility task in the pipeline.

So, do we need to add any Kony related services in the Build Pipeline or a regular Ant task should help ?. Also how can we add any Market place or service connections for Kony in the build pipeline to generate apk in DevOps pipeline?.

Thanks In Advance !!!..

Comment: Do you mean you want to use Azure DevOps Server 2019 build pipeline to build a project created in Kony? Could you share your build definition and entire log (set System.debug to True)? Build, test, and deploy Android apps you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/android?view=azure-devops

Comment: Yes correct, build a project created using Kony Studio.

Comment: Have you checked the link I provided? Is it working for you? If the issue persists, could you share your build definition and entire log (set System.debug to True)?

Comment: I have the DevOps Build Pipeline logs, how can I share it ?

Comment: You can mask the personal information, edit your post and share the log. Have you checked the link I provided?

Answer (score 0):

Before using Azure DevOps Server to build the Android project, you need to make sure the .apk file can be generated locally with `Ant` utility on build agent machine. DevOps pipeline calls `Ant` utility to build the .xml file, if the .apk file can be generated locally using `Ant`, it's supposed to be able to generate during pipeline.

You may try generating a new `build.xml` file with command `android update project -p <PATH TO CHKOUT DIR>` and test again.

Refer to this blog:

https://www.technetexperts.com/mobile/generate-android-app-apk-using-apache-ant/

Or you can follow the link below to use `Gradle` to build your Android project instead of `Ant`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/android?view=azure-devops